# My UI won't update on data changes

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I'm using a local Database (SugarORM) and I'm implementing RXJava to update the UI when the database changes.

As the Activity starts, It subscribes to a new Observer:

```
@Override //This is happening inside doInBackground !
public void onLoading() {
    presenter.getRxProducts().subscribe(new Observer<List<Product>>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(List<Product> products) {
            adapter = new SimpleProductAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_simple_product,
                    products);
        }
    });

}

@Override //This happens inside onPostExecute() !
public void onLoadingComplete() {
    lvProducts.setAdapter(adapter);
    super.onLoadingComplete();
}
```

In my presenter class, the method getRxProducts looks like this:

```
public Observable<List<Product>> getRxProducts(){
    return Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<List<Product>>(){
        @Override
        public List<Product> call() throws Exception {
            return getAllProducts(Product.Sorting.NONE); //This returns a List<Product> object.
        }
    });
}
```

The data looks ok in the UI, but if I make a change to any of the elements of the `Observable<List<Product>>`, I don't see any change being made to the UI. WHat could I me missing?

Comment: you need to `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) & .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` so that you don't block the main ui thread. also  i would set the adapter to listview/recyclerview in onCreate of activity and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` & `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` on your stream.
I think you need to implement that if you want to periodically update your UI.

Answer (score 1):

Attach new adapter to your ListView/RecyclerView or update data in existing adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Where should I attach the new adapter? Inside onNext()?

Comment: Yup, but make sure it is on Android main thread or you will get exception, as mentioned by other answer